# how to calculate the divergence of gradient of an image in matlab?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, video-processing

Is there anyone how can help me how can I calculate the divergence of gradient of an Image in matlab?

Assume that I've got an Image called "I" and I want to calculate this function:

Result = divergence(Gradient(I)) where "I" is a RGB color.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2):

Divergence of the gradient = Laplacian.

Standard way to do it is to use finite differences. Look for example at

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Laplace_operator

and you'll find the classic 2nd order 5-points stencil formula.(I'm assuming you have some basic understanding of finite difference schemes.)

Comment: >> [Ix Iy] = gradient(img);
>> [Ixx Ixy] = gradient(Ix);
>> [Iyx Iyy] = gradient(Iy);
>> diver = Ixx + Iyy;
>> imshow(diver); %% is this code right?

Comment: @claudv, it seems you're into Image Processing - could you assist us open this dedicated group: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/66531/computer-vision/72084 Just vote to questions with less than 10 up votes. Thanks.

Comment: @Moahammadmehdi In principle is right, but I wouldn't apply the gradient operator 3 times, I would apply the Laplace operator once. Be careful that the finite difference formula require some special treatment of the boundary, because the centred finite difference does not apply there, and you have to switch to a one-sided scheme. Keep in mind you can also do it spectrally if you are into FFT (but still the evil is in the boundary!).

Comment: @claudv, Thanks for your response. would you answer to this question that exists in this  [link](https://class.coursera.org/images-003/forum/thread?thread_id=508), cause I can not load any picture in this site, I mean stackoverflow ...